# Setting a SVG fill using Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, audio

I am trying to change the color of an SVG image using audio from the microphone.

I have got the logic written, the color is updated on the SVG element, but nothing changes visually.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
      { audio: true },
      (stream) => {
        var context = new AudioContext();
        var src = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

        var svg = document.querySelector("#rangoli");

        src.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);

        analyser.fftSize = 256;

        var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;

        var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

        function renderFrame() {
          requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

          analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

          for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
            barHeight = dataArray[i] / 2;
            var r = barHeight + 25 * (i / bufferLength);
            var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
            var b = 50;

            svg.setAttribute("fill", `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`);
          }
        }

        renderFrame();
      },
      () => console.log("Error")
    );
  }
};
```

Here is the SVG updating the fill value:
[image: SVG fill updating]

Here is a CodePen demo:
https://codepen.io/GR8z/pen/qBjopZG

Comment: With every frame you are looping through all the values of the dataArray. what you will get in the end will be a value next to 0 + 25 for the red giving you allways a green (since the second value of the rgb color is the biggest and the blue is a constant = 50). To see some change try removing the loop and set the value of i to something at the begining of the array like 2 for example

Comment: Great explanation. That worked like a charm.